# Can't get babel loader to apply to dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

A dependency of my project is using arrow functions and I cannot seem to get babel-loader to transpile the external dependency.

My module section looks like

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
        ]
    }
```

I originally had exclude: /node_modules/(?!superagent)/ in the rules object but removed it to make sure it was not a regex issue.

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react"
  ]
}
```

index.js

```
import superagent from 'superagent'

superagent.get('http://www.google.com')
    .then(result=>console.log('done'))
    .catch(e=>console.error(e));
```

The offending dependency in this case is superagent

I created a minimal repo with the config that shows the issue https://github.com/ksmith97/WebpackIssue

I am not sure what else there is to try here

Edit: To be clear this is for IE 11 support.

Comment: Isnt it `@babel/preset-env` rather than `@babel/env`?

Comment: In babel they introduced preset shorthand as documented in [preset-shorthand](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/presets#preset-shorthand) so @babel/env is @babel/preset-env. I would also reiterate that I have no issues in my source files, the issue only occurs in the dependency files that are imported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the babelrc config directly to babel loader:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(jsx?)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        "@babel/preset-env",
                        "@babel/preset-react"
                    ]
                }
            },
        }]
    }
};
```

This issue got me by surprise too, but looking at the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#file-relative-configuration) you'll see this:

> Searching will stop once a directory containing a package.json is found, so a relative config only applies within a single package.

And in the case of packages inside `node_modules`, all of them will have their own `package.json` file, which will make the `.babelrc` at the root of your project be ignored when the file being compiled is in a package inside `node_modules`.

The loader config does not have this limitation.

Comment: This worked! I can't say I understand why it did though. Do you have an explanation for why it did not use the project's .babelrc on the dependencies?

Comment: Updated the answer to explain the reason.

Comment: Interesting. This sort of makes a .babelrc file useless in a webpack project then if it does not globally apply to all the code involved.  I guess this means its not a bug in babel-loader though but a unexpected babel behavior.

Comment: For anyone else that runs into this issue. This happened on the babel 6.x->7.x migration. Global configs should now be configured in babel.config.js instead of .babelrc

Comment: Just renaming `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js` (and making sure an object is exported from that module) worked for me, as pointed on the Babel documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned your project and executed `npm start` - it bundled the source code into `dist/bundle.js. then I ran this file with`node dist/bundle.js`. Got this:

```
Using browser-only version of superagent in non-browser environment
Error: Browser-only version of superagent could not find XHR
```

So the babel loaders worked.

If you want to use superagent for nodejs, read this - https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/wiki/SuperAgent-for-Webpack

Comment: Well, of course it will work in node where it has support for arrow functions. The issue is that it does not work in Internet Explorer because the arrow functions in superagent are not transpiled(I realize now mentioning IE in the description may have been useful). This can be verified by searching the resulting bundle.js for =>